# php, редирект, узнать конечную ссылку

Tags: редирект, php

Есть ссылка например site.ru/index.php?url=312

При переходе по ней кидает например ан какой-то site2.ru

Как программно определить url адрес этого site2.ru

Час гугла ничего не дал, даже не знаю в какую сторону копать.

---

Узнать адрес куда происходит редирект, пример: 
у меня есть ссылка http://vk.cc/cObdk при клике по ней меня переправит на главную страницу хешкода, мне нужно, чтобы передав скрипту параметр например $url="http://vk.cc/cObdk"; он мне выдал $endurl="http://hashcode.ru/";

Пробовал вот так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
//GET запрос указывается в строке URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $pley[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://сайт.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2');
$endurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Но в итоге я получаю исходный адрес, а не конечный.

Comment: Что-то я вообще ничего не понял... Что означает определить?

Comment: узнать адрес куда происходит редирект, пример 
у меня есть ссылка http://vk.cc/cObdk при клике по ней меня переправит на главную страницу хешкода, мне нужно, чтобі передав скрипту параметр например $url="http://vk.cc/cObdk"; он мне выдал $endurl="http://hashcode.ru/";

Comment: Зачем curl на редирект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = array
(
    'blabla' => 'site.ru',
    'ololo' => 'example.com'
);

if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    if(isset($url[$_GET['url']]))
    {
        echo 'Redirect url: ' . $url[$_GET['url']];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'URL Not Found';
    }
}
//?index.php?url=blabla => site.ru
//?index.php?url=ololo => example.com
```

Все тоже самое можно сделать при запросе к БД.

**UPD**

```
CREATE TABLE `redirect`
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `short_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY(`short_code`)
);

INSERT INTO `redirect` VALUES('1', 'ololo', 'example.com');

if(isset($_GET['url']))
{
    $query = musql_query("SELECT * FROM `redirect` WHERE `short_code` = '".$_GET['url']."'");
    //Дальше сами)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = 'http://google.com'; 
$headers = get_headers($url, 1); 
print "<pre>"; 
print_r($headers['Location']);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Answer (score 1):

Полный пример функции Вы можете найти по адресу: [Follow redirects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php#93163)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще этот URL честно отдаёт 302:

```
wget -S "http://vk.cc/cObdk"
--15:58:47--  http://vk.cc/cObdk
           => `cObdk'
Resolving vk.cc... done.
Connecting to vk.cc[93.186.228.129]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
 1 HTTP/1.1 302 Found
 2 Server: nginx/1.2.4
 3 Date: Mon, 05 Nov 2012 11:58:47 GMT
 4 Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
 5 Content-Length: 0
 6 Connection: keep-alive
 7 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny8
 8 Pragma: no-cache
 9 Cache-control: no-store
10 Location: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
11 Vary: Accept-Encoding
Location: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ [following]
```

Посмотрите, что у вас содержится в CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE. Если что-то другое, значит, где-то что-то не так :) Да, и разрешите CURLOPT_HEADER и посмотрите, что приходит в заголовках.

Answer (score 1):

```
$endurl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: А можете писать более развёрнутые и подробные ответы?

Comment: разумеется могу ) а разве в этой строке что-то ребуется объяснять? это же прямой ответ на вопрос. вполне исчерпывающий